# C - Remove Duplicates from an Array

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, duplicates

I'm quite new to programming, I wrote a code to remove duplicates from an array, logically, it should work, but it doesn't.... I logically tested it multiple times and it made sense...

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rmDuplicates(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            n--;
        }
        return n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    n = rmDuplicates(arr, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if your input is 1 2 3 4 1 your output should me 1 2 3 4 but your code will output 1 2 3 4 1

Comment: You are only removing duplicates if they are consecutive (because of the `if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])` test); you are okay with this?

Comment: you are checking with only consecutive numbers, so it does  not work if duplicates are not consecutive, in the first loop should check 0th element with all all other elements, then repeat the procedure till the end.

Comment: 'arr[i+1]' OOB access when i equals n-1.

Answer (score 2):

Your "return n" is in the wrong place, and returns after the first cycle.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
        for(j=i+1;j<n-1;j++) {
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];                              
        }
        n--;
    }
    return n; // <---- this
}
// <-- should be here.
```

As confirmation, if I move the `return n;` outside the loop, the code works. But it only removes **consecutive** duplicates, because you only check arr[i] against its consecutive, arr[i+1].

(Also, the cycle ought to stop at n-1, because otherwise arr[n-1+1] is arr[n] which is outside the array).

A final issue is that if you have, say,

```
                   n
 ...5,..., 5, 5, 6
    i      j
```

and you check the first 5 against the second, and find it a duplicate, then shift all that follows by one step, in the j-th position you will have a 5 again, but j will now be incremented and you will test the first 5 against the 6 instead of the third 5, not finding the duplicate:

```
                n
 ...5,..., 5, 6
    i         j
```

For this reason, when you find a match, you need to rewind j by one and repeat that test:

```
int rmDuplicates(int arr[], int n) {
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
        for (j=i+1; j < n; j++) {
                if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    n--;
                    for (k=j;k<n;k++) {
                        arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                    }
                    j--;
                }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

From a performance point of view, the above algorithm is O(n^2), that is, if the array list doubles, the algorithm takes four times as long; if it trebles, it takes nine times as long.

A better algorithm would therefore be to first sort the array in-place, so that `1 3 2 7 2 3 5` becomes `1 2 2 3 3 5 7` (this has a cost of O(n log n), which grows more slowly ); then you just "compress" the array skipping duplicates, which is O(n) and gets you `1 2 3 5 7`

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 1; j < n;) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        j++;
        continue;
    }
    i++;
    if (j != (i+1)) {
        arr[i] = arr[j];
    }
    j++;
}
n = i+1;
```

Comment: return does not make sense here, but it is not the cause for not removing duplicates here

Comment: @sravs I believe it was; if I move that instruction outside the loop, the code works (not perfectly, see amended answer, but better - it now finds consecutive duplicates where before it did not).

Comment: @LSerni Thank you so much, but how come sorting the array is O(n log n) and not O(n) ?

Comment: That is somewhat complicated to explain. It has to do with the Shannon entropy of the array. Your unsorted array represents one of n! possible permutations, and its entropy is log(n!)/log(2). There is a formula stating that log(n!) tends to n (log n - 1), and you then need o(n log n) bits to uniquely identify your sorting. Since each comparison is one bit of information (arr[i] is either > arr[j] or not), you end up requiring o(n log n) comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t removeDups(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr && size > 1)
    {
        for(size_t current = 0; current < size - 1; current++)
        {
            size_t original_size = size;
            size_t copypos = current + 1;
            for(size_t cpos = current + 1; cpos < original_size; cpos++)
            {
                if(arr[current] == arr[cpos])
                {
                    if(cpos < original_size -1)
                    {
                        if(arr[current] != arr[cpos + 1])
                        {
                            arr[copypos++] = arr[cpos + 1];
                            cpos++;
                        }
                    }
                    size--;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[copypos++] = arr[cpos];
                }
           }
        }
    }
    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,1,8,8,2,2,2,2};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    size = removeDups(arr, size);
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[index]);
    }
}
```